# git: Is it safe to cancel a long running commit?

Tags: git

I accidentally tried to commit a large file (~250 MB) to my local git repo about an hour ago. The commit still hasn't finished an hour later and the vm I'm in is running like molasses. I want to cancel the commit (ctrl-c) but I'm afraid of what that will do.

Is it safe to interrupt an in progress commit? If not, are there any other options here?

Comment: I think you meant *push* rather than *commit*

Comment: Do it. It won't damage anything. AFAIK

Comment: @Grabriele Nope, my last command was a commit.

Comment: I should have realized this before I asked... but either way I still have the files that I made the changes in, so even if my local repo gets messed up it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no other really important changes in that commit that you can't lose, just abort it, you can always `git reset` since it's a local commit only.

(Just don't `push` your changes to a remote repository and almost everything can be solved rather easy.)

Comment: It wouldn't be disastrous to lose the changes, but they do make up a couple hours work that I'd rather not redo. I think what I'm really looking for is whether or not git commit is atomic?. Searches for that haven't turned up anything conclusive.

Comment: Git commits are atomic.  But one additional piece of info you probably should be aware of... Git isn't really meant for big, frequently changing, binary objects... though 250Mb doesn't seem that big to me, and not sure whether your object is binary and frequently changing.  But even one big file anywhere in your repo can significantly slow down cloning and/or the fetch that includes that object.